# How to get mysql records from a statement that has a LIKE clause for the TABLE_NAMES

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select records from two tables. These two tables have the prefix "shop_".

How do I select the records for both shops in a sql statement?

My current statement:

```
// Select
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT name, html_id, price FROM database_name WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'shop%'");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $arr[] = $row;
}

$name = [];
foreach($arr as $arrs)
{
    $name[] = array(0 => $arrs['name'], 1 => $arrs['html_id'], 2 => $arrs['price']); //here
}
$stmt->close();

print_r($name);
```

The mysql php current **error** is:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on boolean in C:\wamp642\www\webcart\search.php on line 17 and line 17 is: $stmt->execute();
```

I can get the tables to "show" with this command:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("show tables like '%shop%'");
```

But it doesn't get the records, just an object I think.

The output of "show tables like '%shop%'" prints 2 arrays just like it should, but the arrays are empty with no data/records.

I'm thinking it's the sql statement that needs work. Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I've also tried:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='feeds' AND TABLE_NAME LIKE 'shop%'");
```

**EDIT: The contents of search.php**

```
<?php 

include 'define.php';

$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_database);
if($mysqli->connect_error)
{
    ?><script>var profiles_delete_modal_1 = ' Error 3: Problem deleteing profile. Make sure database login credentials are correct.';</script>
    <script>$(".modal").css({"opacity":"1", "z-index":"100"});$(".modal_mid").html("<pre>" + profiles_delete_modal_1 + "</pre>");setTimeout(function(){$(".modal").css({"opacity":"0", "z-index":"-100"});},5000);</script><?php
    exit;
}

$shop = 'shop';
// Select
//$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("show tables like '%shop%'");
//$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM feeds WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'shop%'");
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT name, html_id, price FROM database_name WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'shop%'");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $arr[] = $row;
}

$n=0;
$name = [];
foreach($arr as $arrs)
{
    $name[] = array(0 => $arrs['name'], 1 => $arrs['html_id'], 2 => $arrs['price']); //here
    $n++;
}
$stmt->close();

print_r($name);
```

**and the contents of define.php:**

```
$www_dir = 'webcart';
$url_root = 'http://localhost/' . $www_dir . '';
$www_dir_slash = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '' . $www_dir . '/';
$host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'webcart_admin';
$db_password = 'asd123';
$db_database = 'shop';

$_SESSION['host'] = $host;
$_SESSION['db_user'] = $db_user;
$_SESSION['db_password'] = $db_password;
$_SESSION['db_database'] = $db_database;
```

**EDIT**

From going on the answer stated below I've been able to create a string like this:

```
SELECT name, html_id, price FROM shop_a UNION shop_b
```

however it won't execute properly.

This is my code:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT name, html_id, price FROM shop_a UNION shop_b"); 
$result = $stmt->execute();
```

It gives the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on boolean in C:\wamp642\www\webcart\search.php on line 43
```

**EDIT** Got it.

I'll post the answer up soon. The statement goes like this:

```
"SELECT name, html_id, price FROM shop_a UNION SELECT name, html_id, price from shop_b"
```

Comment: Please show us the contents of `search.php`. `SHOW` doesn't fetch data, it is expected behavior.

Comment: Added. Yes I suspected this was default behaviour.

Comment: `SELECT` query is used to fetch data from DB tables, not DB itself. So you need to provide a table name in the `FROM` part of your query.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer pretty much from musafar, although I needed to get to the objects in the array. So I used some foreach loops to do this seeing as I don't know any other way. If there's another way to get to mysqli_object data, please let me know.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'shop' AND table_name LIKE 'shop%'"); 

//table_schema is the database name and 'shop%' is the search string

$stmt->execute();
$tables = $stmt->get_result();
$stmt->close();

$arr = [];
foreach($tables as $tabless)
{
    $arr[] = $tabless;
}

foreach($arr as $arrs)
{
    $toby[] = implode(',',$arrs);   
}       

$tobyy = implode(' UNION SELECT name, html_id, price from ',$toby);

//$tobyy = "shop_a UNION SELECT name, html_id, price from shop_b"

$arr = [];  
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT name, html_id, price FROM " . $tobyy); 
$result = $stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $arr[] = $row;
}

$n=0;
$name = [];
foreach($arr as $arrs)
{
    $name[$n] = array(0 => $arrs['name'], 1 => $arrs['html_id'], 2 => $arrs['price']); //here
    $n++;
}
$stmt->close();

print_r($name);

//$name = "Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Chromecast [1] => chromecast [2] => 59 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => EZCast [1] => ezcast [2] => 49 ) )"
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT` query is used to fetch data from DB tables, not DB itself. So you need to provide a table name in the `FROM` part of your query.

Considering you're trying to fetch data from similar tables (same fields)...

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'wp_105424' AND table_name LIKE 'shop%'");
$stmt->execute();
$tables = $stmt->get_result();
$dataStmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT name, html_id, price FROM " . implode(',', $tables)); // name, html_id, price should be in all tables that starts with *shop*
$dataStmt->execute();
$data = $dataStmt->get_result();
```

And you may need to add conditions to handle all scenarios.

Comment: I see. I'm trying to do it with your code but I get the following error: `Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in C:\wamp642\www\webcart\search.php on line 21`

Comment: $tables echo's (using print_r) to "1". Its not a label or anything.

Comment: Yes, you need to get the result using `get_result()`. See updated answer.

Comment: $tables is still coming out as a mysqli_object: `mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 1 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 2 [type] => 0 ) `. I used foreach loops to iterate the arrays out to get the following line: `SELECT name, html_id, price FROM shop_a UNION shop_b` but it still won't execute that line for some reason.

Comment: sorry, I was busy to test the code. You can use `array_column` to extract just the `table_name`s from the $tables array.